# SQL removing a whole row based on a single info

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with repeating information and I need to remove a whole row based on a single entry. Here is a picture that shows better what I need.

[image: My Problematic Table]

```
SELECT 
FIN.NUMCONTRATO ,FIN.NUFIN, (SELECT DISTINCT FIN.NURENEG) AS RENEGOCIACAO, FIN.DTVENC, FIN.DHBAIXA, FIN.VLRDESDOB AS VALOR_ORIGINAL, AD_STATUS AS STATUS_CONTRATO
FROM
SANKHYA.TGFFIN FIN 
INNER JOIN SANKHYA.TCSCON CON ON (FIN.NUMCONTRATO = CON.NUMCONTRATO) 
WHERE 
FIN.NUMCONTRATO > 0 AND FIN.CODEMP = 1
AND YEAR(FIN.DTVENC) >= YEAR(GETDATE())-1
ORDER BY FIN.NUMCONTRATO, FIN.NUFIN, FIN.DTVENC
```

The column RENEGOCIACAO has these "duplicates" 60448 and 66016, the problem is, only the data on this column is duplicated, and the rest of the row is totally different. All methods I tried to remove so far have failed.

I need to check if there are results with the same value in the column RENEGOCIACAO, and if I have, remove the whole row where the oldest "duplicate" value was found.
If removing the row is not possible, changing the value from the oldest entry on the RENEGOCIACAO column to NULL or anything else different from its origin would also work for me.

I tried Distinct, tried messing with WHERE conditions, tried every solution I could find on Google, tried UNION... I tried so many things and can't remember them all.

Comment: Why do you not have a primary key in this table?  Basic normalization 1NF.

Answer (score 1):

Transform your question to "delete all entries where one exists with the same `RENEGOCIACAO` and a later `DTVENC`", and the query writes itself.

Delete all older entries (leaving only the newest):

```
Delete From SANKHYA.TGFFIN
Where Exists(Select *
             From SANKHYA.TGFFIN As Newer
             Where SANKHYA.TGFFIN.RENEGOCIACAO = Newer.RENEGOCIACAO 
               And SANKHYA.TGFFIN.DTVENC < Newer.DTVENC)
```

If you want to delete only the oldest one:

```
Delete From SANKHYA.TGFFIN
Where Exists(Select *
             From SANKHYA.TGFFIN As Newer
             Where SANKHYA.TGFFIN.RENEGOCIACAO = Newer.RENEGOCIACAO 
               And SANKHYA.TGFFIN.DTVENC < Newer.DTVENC)
      And SANKHYA.TGFFIN.DTVENC = (Select Min(DTVENC)
                                   From SANKHYA.TGFFIN As OldestDate
                                   Where OldestDate.RENEGOCIACAO = SANKHYA.TGFFIN.RENEGOCIACAO)
```

The only assumption here is that you don't have renegotiations on the same day, let me know if that does happen.

Comment: you unsung hero. Not to mention the only sensible answer here.

Answer (score -1):

Because the other columns in your table have unique information, you can use that to your benefit.

You can delete single rows by making a unique combination of values:

```sql
DELETE FROM SANKHYA.TGFFIN 
  WHERE NURENEG=60448 AND NUFIN=7913473
```

This exact where clause may not work for data in SANKHYA.TGFFIN. Because RENEGOCIACAO is calculated from a SELECT DISTINCT subquery it is difficult to know for sure how the NURENEG column in SANKHYA stores data.

If you have a large number of duplicates, a more complex query can remove them all at once.

Answer (score -2):

This issue may be solved with a windowing expression similar to

```sql
DELETE FROM fin
WHERE  ( Row_number()
           OVER (
             partition BY renegociacao
             ORDER BY numcontrato DESC) ) > 1
```

Note that this query will delete all rows with duplicate values of renegociacao, keeping rows where numcontrato is largest out of each set.

Depending on the database, you may have to jump through some hoops to get an expression like this to run.

Comment: your answer doesnt meet his requirements. You are removing everything but the oldest. he needs the oldest dupe to be removed. Since youre very close, i wont post my own answer but you do need to adjust your answer.

Comment: youre still deleting too much. his requirements state "where the oldest "duplicate" value was found." This means only delete the oldest (i.e. 1 record) duplicate. Youre original solution wouldve worked by changing the ">" to a "="

Comment: if he intended to say "all duplicates" then OP should clarify his requirements. I might be knit picking here but its important to deliver whats asked not what you think he wants.

Comment: I chose > 1 rather than a single match because I'm assuming a requirement that the resulting table contain no duplicates in the renegociacao column.

Comment: see my previous comment - you should not make assumptions on what requirements might be

Comment: Hey guys, thank you all for your answers. Yea, i need to remove only the oldest duped value. In the 60448 example, only the 2023-01-30 should gom the newer one should stay.  This whole thing happens when clients dont pay on the right days and them we have to recalculate the whole thing. A new Financial Id Number is created and i end up with 2 entrys of the same bill.

Comment: I was thinking. Maybe i wont delete the entry, maybe just filter it so it doesnt show on my query is better... never know when management could request older data... i dont want to tell them i deleted it hahaha. To filter the whole thing, the logic remains the same ? If i trade the Delete for another clause, will i need to change a lot more things ?

Comment: Good idea to not delete the rows if you may need them! I would suggest creating a view that groups the data by transaction, effectively combining the two rows instead of filtering out one. Grouping by renegociacao would allow you do use aggregations like max or min to get the important information about each transaction.